Questions about counters
I need help. I want to show like "Example 5.1.1"(Means Chapter 5, Section 1 the first example", but when I rewrite code I got a problem. Here's my code:
% Counter Reset
\pgfkeys{
/infoBulle/math/.cd,
counterReset/.store in=\infoBulle@mathCounterReset,
counterReset = chapter, % Use the new counter}



%------Example-------
    \NewTranslation{english}{example}{Example}
    \NewTranslation{french}{example}{Exemple}
    \NewTranslation{german}{example}{Beispiel}
    \newcounter{example}[\infoBulle@mathCounterReset] % The counter will reset at each new section
    % Redefine how the counter is printed
    % \renewcommand{\theexample}{\thesection.\arabic{example}}
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{example}{o}{%
        \stepcounter{example}%
        \begin{mdframed}[%
            style=infoBulle,
            linecolor=mathematicalColor,
            frametitle=\@titleContentMath{\GetTranslation{example}}{\theexample.\thesection}{#1}
            ]\relax%
    }{%
        \end{mdframed}%
    }

It shows "example 5.1.5.1". So how should I amend it?

Welcome to TeX.se! Please don't post code fragments. Instead edit your question and include the fragment in a compilable document that people can play with.

Why aren't you using \counterwithin{example}{section} and \renewcommand\theexample{\thesection.\arabic{example}} or whatever?

@AlanMunn Hi,I am sorry because this is a fold with pkgs and other documents, So I cant post all the documents. I am using a template but I am trying to rewrite some commands. This settings were wrote in .sty and I am not good at it.

@cfr Because I'm rewrite a template . I want to use that presence:)

Templates are usually a bad idea but, regardless, it doesn't mean you can't make an example. It just takes more patience when you're got a more complicated document.
